# What is the difference between ROC curve and Confusion matrix?

Tags: model, roc, confusion-matrix

I'm confused about the ROC curve and confusion matrix. The area under the ROC curve represents the accuracy of the classifier. But the confusion matrix also shows a measure of accuracy. So which method is better for me to find the accuracy of the model?

Answer (score 3):

AUC isn't the same thing as accuracy.

The situation where you want to use a ROC curve or the AUC is when you're evaluating a continuous measure and don't have a clear choice of where to make the cutoff; it describes the range of possible behaviors between the true positive and false positive rates.

A confusion matrix is for when you have something divided into distinct categories, and tells you the full behavior of the classifier there.

If you know the total number of positives and negatives in your test set, though, you can reconstruct a confusion matrix from any point on the ROC curve.

Comment: "The situation where you want to use a ROC curve or the AUC is when you're evaluating a continuous measure and don't have a clear choice of where to make the cutoff." ------- But how does one use the ROC curve to choose the proper cutoff?